# Unhandled exception MSVCRTD.DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I write a programe in visual studio 6.0 it is a graphical user interface. i am using MFC classes for GUI it store records for books. In that programe i got a unhandled exception  Access violation error while i tried to view the records. I save records in a file using file handling thorugh CFile class. When i press OK button on the error message box it lead me to a browsing box asking for a file name as OUTPUT.C but i cannot found such kind of file and when i click Cancel button on this browse box it will take me to the Disassembly file pointing an arrow to this line `1021674C   movsx       edx,byte ptr [ecx]`. I want your help desprately this is my final assignment and i have to submit it tommorrow morning please help me out.
i hope i describe problem correctly so you guys can understand it properly please help me out.
Code of the programe is below :

```
    #include "afxwin.h"
#include "resource.h"

struct books
{
    char bookname[25];
    char authorname[40];
    float price;
    int copies;
    unsigned int ispn;
    int page;
    char issue_date[15];
    char avail[10];

};

CFile fp("book.txt",CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeNoTruncate|CFile::modeReadWrite);
CString b_name;
unsigned int b_ispn;

class about_dialog:public CDialog
{
public:
    about_dialog():CDialog(IDD_DIALOG1)
    {
    }

};

class add_dialog:public CDialog
{
private:
    struct books b;
    CString s[4];
    public:

        add_dialog():CDialog(IDD_DIALOG2)
        {
            b.price =0.0;
            b.copies = b.page = 0;
            b.ispn = 0 ;

        }

        void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *p)
        {
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT1,s[0]);//name
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT2,s[1]);//author
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT3,b.copies);//copies
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT4,b.ispn);//ispn
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT5,b.price);//price
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT6,b.page);//pages

            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO5,s[2]);//issu date
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO6,s[3]);//availabel

        }
        void save()
        {
            CDialog::OnOK();

            strcpy(b.bookname,s[0]);
            strcpy(b.authorname,s[1]);
            strcpy(b.issue_date,s[2]);
            strcpy(b.avail,s[3]);


            fp.SeekToEnd();
            fp.Write(&b,sizeof(b));
        }

        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(add_dialog,CDialog)
ON_COMMAND(IDSAVE,save)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class getbook_dialog:public CDialog
{
public:

    struct books b;
    getbook_dialog():CDialog(IDD_DIALOG3)
    {
        b_name="";
        b_ispn=0;
    }

    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *p)
    {

        DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT1,b_ispn);
        DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT2,b_name);
    }

};

class modify_dialog:public CDialog
{
private:
    CString s[4];
    struct books b;

    public:

        modify_dialog(struct books bb):CDialog(IDD_DIALOG2)
        {
            b=bb;
            s[0]=bb.bookname;
            s[1]=bb.authorname;
            s[2]=bb.issue_date;
            s[3]=bb.avail;


        }


    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *p)
        {
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT1,s[0]);//name
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT2,s[1]);//author
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT3,b.copies);//copies
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT4,b.ispn);//ispn
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT5,b.price);//price
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT6,b.page);//pages
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO5,s[2]);//issu date
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO6,s[3]);//availabel

        }
        void save()
        {
            CDialog::OnOK();

            strcpy(b.bookname,s[0]);
            strcpy(b.authorname,s[1]);
            strcpy(b.issue_date,s[2]);
            strcpy(b.avail,s[3]);

            fp.Seek(-(long)sizeof(b),CFile::current);
            fp.Write(&b,sizeof(b));

        }

        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(modify_dialog,CDialog)
ON_COMMAND(IDSAVE,save)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class myframe: public CFrameWnd
{
public:

    myframe()
    {
        CString mywindowclass;
        CBrush mybrush;
        mybrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));

        mywindowclass = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW |CS_VREDRAW,AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW),mybrush,AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1));

        Create(mywindowclass,"DATABASE",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,rectDefault,0,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));

    }

    void about()
    {
        about_dialog diag;
        diag.DoModal();
    }

    void addrec()
    {
        Invalidate();
        add_dialog diag;
        diag.DoModal();
    }

    void byname()
    {
        struct books b;

        CClientDC d(this);
        CRect r;
        int y;
        char str[90];
        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;
        GetClientRect(&r);
        CBrush mybrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        while(fp.Read(&b,sizeof(b))>=sizeof(b))
        {
            sprintf(str,"%-25s %-40s",b.bookname,b.copies);
            d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));

            y+=15;
        }
    }

    void author()
    {
        struct books b;

        CClientDC d(this);
        int y;
        char str[90];
        CRect r;

        GetClientRect(&r);
        CBrush mybrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;

        while(fp.Read(&b,sizeof(b))>=sizeof(b))
        {
            sprintf(str,"%-25s %-20s %-6u %-10s",b.bookname,b.authorname,b.page,b.copies);
            d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));
            y+=15;
        }
    }

    void ispn()
    {
        struct books b;
        CClientDC d(this);
        int y;
        char str[90];
        CRect r;
        GetClientRect(&r);
        CBrush mybrush (RGB(255,255,255));
        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;

        while(fp.Read(&b,sizeof(b))>=sizeof(b))
        {
            sprintf(str,"%-25s %-20s %-15s %-15s",b.bookname,b.authorname,b.ispn,b.avail);
        //  d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));
            y+=15;
        }
    }


    void modifyrec()
    {
        Invalidate();

        bool found;

        struct books b;

        getbook_dialog diag;
        if(diag.DoModal()==IDOK)
        {
            found = false;

            fp.SeekToBegin();

            while(fp.Read(&b,sizeof(b))>=sizeof(b))
            {
                if(b.ispn == b_ispn && strcmp(b.bookname,b_name)==0)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(found == true )
            {
                modify_dialog mdiag(b);
                mdiag.DoModal();
            }
            else
                MessageBox("Record Not Found","Modify Record....");
        }
    }

    void delrec()
    {
        bool found;
        struct books b;

        Invalidate();

        getbook_dialog diag;
        if(diag.DoModal()==IDOK)
        {
            found = false;
            fp.SeekToBegin();

            CFile ft("temp.dat",CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
            while(fp.Read(&b,sizeof(b))>= sizeof(b))
            {
                if(b.ispn==b_ispn && strcmp(b.bookname,b_name)==0)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                else 
                    ft.Write(&b,sizeof(b));

            }

            if(found == false )
                    MessageBox("Record Not Found","Delete Record....");

            fp.Close();
            ft.Close();

            CFile::Remove("book.txt");
            CFile::Rename("temp.dat","book.txt");
            fp.Open("book.txt",CFile::modeCreate |CFile::modeNoTruncate |CFile::modeReadWrite);
        }
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myframe,CFrameWnd)

ON_COMMAND(101,about)
ON_COMMAND(201,addrec)
ON_COMMAND(301,byname)
ON_COMMAND(302,author)
ON_COMMAND(303,ispn)
ON_COMMAND(401,modifyrec)
ON_COMMAND(501,delrec)

END_MESSAGE_MAP()


class myapp:public CWinApp
{
    public:

        int InitInstance()
        {
            myframe *fr;
            fr = new myframe;
            fr->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            m_pMainWnd = fr;

            return 1;
        }
};
myapp app;
```

Comment: Your program is crashing in the internals of the standard library, Winows knows that the file where the crash happened is output.c but it doesn't know where that file is so it asks you. But that doesn't really matter. Press cancel like you did, and then look for the **stack trace** or **call stack** that shows where your program crashed. As you go up the stack trace you'll go from library code back into your code. That will give you a better idea of where and why the crash happens. If you can find the line in your code where this crash happens someone might have a chance of helping you.

Comment: this 0x002f1940 {myframe hWnd=0x000b0684}   see this line if it might be helpful for you

Comment: That's no help. You have to go up the call stack to find somewhere in your code. At least we need that line number in your code where the crash happened. But your best chance is to learn how to use the debugger for yourself. It's hard to do a debugging session over the internet.

Comment: Got the error and correct it thanks alot for the support guys i am very sorry for my wrong and difficult english.

` sprintf(str,"%-25s %-40s",b.bookname,b.copies);` this line cause the crash

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Nothing wrong with your English.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my MFC, but it seems that in your `add_dialog::save()` OnOK should be called at the end, I think that OnOK essentially closes the dialog and the data in your dialog might get invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Access violation means you used a NULL pointer.

for instance:

```
class A
{
public:
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    A *pa = NULL;
    cout << pa->num << endl; // <----------------access violation

    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you look at the call stack, and find out where is the NULL pointer.